# If Statement Not Returning an Output

Tags: java, if-statement

I am finishing an assignment for Introduction to Java and have been stuck for hours.

When I run the code below, enter the integers and hit enter, I do not get anything in the output. Please help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class U3A1_DebugFixIFStmts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("If Statements"); 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // Prompt User to Enter Three Integers
        System.out.print("Enter three integers: ");
        int firstChoice = input.nextInt();
        int secondChoice = input.nextInt();
        int thirdChoice = input.nextInt();
    
        //Determine & print the state of choices made
        if (firstChoice == 0)
        {System.out.println("State of choices: \n" +
                    "no choices made yet");}
        else if (secondChoice == 0)
        {System.out.println("State of choices: \n" +
                    "user made first choice (" + firstChoice + ")\n" +
                    "number of choices = 1");}
        else if (thirdChoice == 0)
        {System.out.println("State of choices: \n" +
                    "user made first choice (" + firstChoice + ")\n" +
                    "user made second choice (" + secondChoice + ")\n" +
                    "number of choices = 2");}
        
        else 
        {System.out.println("State of choices: \n" +
                    "user made first choice (" + firstChoice + ")\n" +
                    "user made second choice (" + secondChoice + ")\n" +
                    "user made third choice (" + thirdChoice + ")\n" +
                    "number of choices = 3");}
    
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to enter 3 numbers before it prints anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
int firstChoice = input.nextInt();
int secondChoice = input.nextInt();
int thirdChoice = input.nextInt();
```

These three lines of your codes require your input before your program moves ahead. Hence, give 3 numbers and then you'll see it work.